# amazon redshift, sqlworkbench/j

Tags: amazon-redshift, sql-workbench-j

I am running sqlworkbench/j on ubuntu. I am not able to connect to the database through proxy server. How to setup the proxy setting of the Amazon redshift jdbc driver.

Comment: what proxy? can you clarify?

Comment: I am using my institute proxy server
host: 10.3.100.207
port -8080

Answer (score 1):

Did you allow inbound traffic from the proxy to redshift? Normally you would provide access using a security group with an inbound TCP Rule from a given IP on Port 5438 (default Redshift port). You would have to find out and enter your proxy's IP adress.